# Problems with WebView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to load a webpage with a web view with the following code:

```
let url = "http://apple.com"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    WebView1.loadRequest(request)
```

But whenever I run my iOS application it crashes and brings up this screen:

[image: Whenever I run my iOS Application, I get this]

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a new type called `Optional`. It is used to express nullability. You need to unwrap each optional value before you use it. You unwrap using an `if let` statement:

```
let url = "http://apple.com"
if let requestURL = NSURL(string:url) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    WebView1.loadRequest(request)
}
```

But you also have another problem. Why isn't your string being parsed into a URL? Are you really using "http://apple.com" or is that just an example? Your URL string is malformed

Comment: I'll try that. I got this code from another site and they used the "http://apple.com", I plan on using a different URL though.

Answer (score 0):

This code only works with apples website if you want to use it on another website you have to change the info.plist file and add the url. Hope this helps you out

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

let rect = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: rect)

let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com”)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

```
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```